# Using Natsort on a multi-index Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index, natsort

I have the following DF which is multi-index due to using groupby():

| date | code | quarter | average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20201231 | ABCD | Q1 | 3135 |
|  |  | Q10 | 3135 |
|  |  | Q11 | 3135 |
|  |  | Q12 | 3135 |
|  |  | Q2 | 3135 |

I'm trying to sort by date, code and then quarter which are part of the multi-index, however I want to use a Natsort method such that the order is Q1, Q2, ....Q9, Q10... but get various errors when I try do so. My best attempt is:

`df.sort_index(level=['date','code','quarter'], ascending=[True, True, True], key=natsort_keygen())`

I receive the following error:

> NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex

I'm using Pandas version 1.1.5, Natsort 8.1.0, Python 3.6.9

Comment: can you provide the input as DataFrame constructor? Do you have NaNs?

Comment: Hi, there are not any NaNs as I removed them when cleaning the underlying dataset

Comment: Does this happen without the `key` (e.g. without `natsort_keygen()`)? That can help narrow the issue.

Comment: If I remove key = natsort_keygen() then I do not have any errors and sorting is performed in the normal manner